# Проблема с записью в БД, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, появилась проблема, сказали прикрутить платёжный шлюз free-kassa и вот у меня огромная проблема с записью в БД.

Нам шлют запрос:

> MERCHANT_ORDER_ID=1000++%EF%EE%E4%EF%E8%F1%F7%E8%EA%EE%E2+%ED%E0+%EB%E8%F7%ED%F3%FE+%F1%F2%F0%E0%ED%E8%F6%F3+%28VK%29&P_PHONE=&P_EMAIL=test%40yandex.ua&CUR_ID=45&AMOUNT=3&MERCHANT_ID=38053&SIGN=5bc4c57fc7769ed8b2a1c9f9697740e7&intid=12454229&us_name=Саня&us_social=VK&us_email=test@test.ru&us_link=http://test.ru/

Я его пишу отдельно в файл, и отдельно в БД. 
Так вот, в файле всё записывается нормально, а вот в БД не пишется информация на кириллице. Причём самое смешное, я уже отдельно записал SQL-запрос, который PHP производит и вручную в ПМА его произвёл и всё записалось идеально, а вот через mysql_query ну никак, вместо кириллицы ничего.

[image: screenshot bd]

Попробовал изменить кодировку БД windows-1251(ибо даже в ней мы передаем данные на шлюз, но в файле всё же все нормально пишется) и никак вообще, тот же результат.

UPD: 
Ответ поддержки: "Support7A Была,да) не решили пишите на латинице все". 
Переобразование в base64 тоже не помогло из-за кодировки(см.комментарии).  Возможно, ещё будут предложения?

Comment: Что дальше вы с этой записью из бд хотите делать?

Comment: @Visman, выводить в небольшой панельке и всё. В дальнейшем будет под редактирование затрагиваться только булевой столбец status.

Comment: Ответ поддержки: "Support7A
Была,да)
не решили
пишите на латинице все". Использовать регулярку или есть функция какая-то?

Comment: Может стоит тогда конвертировать в **base64** перед записью, чтобы с кодировками не мучатся, а при выводе назад в оригинальный текст декодировать?

Comment: @Visman, а ведь идея, спасибо. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @Visman, не помогло. Возвращает в итоге белеберду: "MTAwMCAg7+7k7+jx9+jq7uIg7eAg6+j37fP+IPHy8ODt6PbzIChWSyk=". Пробовал и выставлять windows-1251, и UTF-8 - везде одно и тоже. Причём в файл же пишет с нормальной кодировкой, а тут даже кодировать не может. Бред какой-то.

Comment: Я уже не знаю, что и делать. Уже думаю писать в файл имя, потом в следующей строке его оттуда брать, вставлять в БД, и очищать файл. UPD: Попробовал, аналогично. Тут огромная дилема с кодировкой.

Comment: В общем, на данный момент из решений вижу: пишем функцию кириллица->латиница, и при выводе латиница->кириллица. Пока, вроде как, работает всё сносно. Но, в целом, возможно всё же мы сможем побороться с кодировкой.

Comment: Нет там у вас ни какой белеберды. Вот http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07ef12cb5e32bf06d5eff5d118e8b8c2989fb73a все читаемо.

Comment: а использовать **iconv** пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если один и тот же запрос в PMA работает как надо, а из php скрипта имеет проблемы с кириллицей, значит сервер не понимает с какой кодировкой вы работаете. PMA указывает кодировку, а вы нет!
Вам необходимо выполнить

```
SET NAMES ваша_кодировка_страниц
```

сразу после соединения. Здесь упоминается кодировка вашего клиента, а не кодировка данных в базе (они могут совпадать или раздичаться). Или используйте аналогичные этому вызовы mysqli/PDO

- https://secure.php.net/mysqli_set_charset
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#113498
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#44707

Comment: Точно, Вы правы! У меня set names стоял, но я уже благополучно забыл, что его использовал и там utf8 стоит, ибо подключал файл отдельно и на глазах его не было. Спасибо Вам, а то мы тут уже какие только костыли не делали :)